# Using Cayley's theorem to explicitly describe permutation groups isomorphic to a given group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

A textbook question asks to test one's understanding of the proof of Cayley's theorem by asking for an explicit description of a subgroup of $S_4$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$, and of one isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$. It's not hard to use the proof to make educated guesses, and then verify. But the question might be read as suggesting that implicit in the proof is a general method for converting some kind of explicit presentation of a (let's say finite) group $G$ into an explicit description of an isomorphic subgroup of $S_n$, where $n = |G|$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. It's weird to see you say "use the proof to make educated guesses," when the proof directly says how to turn $G$ into a subgroup of $S_G$.

Comment: My question was about $S_{|G|}$, not $S_G$. I understand that a set isomorphism $G \to \{1,\dots,|G|\}$ will define a group isomorphism $S_G \to S_{|G|}$ and thence an embedding of $G$ in $S_{|G|}$. But the phrasing of the question suggested to me that the given proof of Cayley's theorem was supposed to define a natural embedding in $S_{|G|}$, and I wasn't seeing that. As is implicit in the helpful answers below, it isn't meant to, and it's fairly clear now that it couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you a hint. Write down the group in question as an ordered set, let's take $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$: $\{x_1=e_G, x_2,x_3,x_4\}$. Multiply from the left (from the *right* gives you the same answer, this group is abelian!) with $x_2$ and the set becomes $\{x_2,x_1,x_4, x_3\}$, hence the permutation $(1 2)(3 4)$. Continue this for all the other elements of $G$ and see which permutations in $S_4$ you get. This will be your isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ in $S_4$. If you have understood this, do the same for $\mathbb{Z}_4$. This recipe works for every group, try for example the quaternion group of order $8$ to see which subgroup of $S_8$ is isomorphic to that one. Experiment with a *left* and *right* multiplication. Are the permutations the same?

Answer (score 1):

> A textbook question asks to test one's understanding of the proof of Cayley's theorem by asking for an *explicit description* of a subgroup *of $S_4$* isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4$, and of one isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_2$.

I interpret the parts in italics (mine) as an invitation to the full technicality behind Cayley's theorem.

Cayley's embedding $\varphi\colon \mathbb Z_4\hookrightarrow S_{\mathbb Z_4}$ is defined by:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&[0]&&\mapsto [0]+\_ \\
&[1]&&\mapsto [1]+\_ \\
&[2]&&\mapsto [2]+\_ \\
&[3]&&\mapsto [3]+\_ \\
\end{alignat}
To embed the subgroup $\varphi(\mathbb Z_4)\le S_{\mathbb Z_4}$ into $S_4$, you've got to choose any amongst the $4!$ bijections $\mathbb Z_4\to \{1,2,3,4\}$, say for example $f$ defined by:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&[0]&&\mapsto 1 \\
&[1]&&\mapsto 2 \\
&[2]&&\mapsto 3 \\
&[3]&&\mapsto 4 \\
\tag1
\end{alignat}
Then, the isomorphism $\psi_f\colon S_{\mathbb Z_4}\to S_4$, defined by $\sigma\mapsto f\sigma f^{-1}$, does the job. For example:
\begin{alignat}{1}
(\psi_f([0]+\_))(1) &= (f([0]+\_) f^{-1})(1) \\
&= f(([0]+\_)(f^{-1}(1))) \\
&= f([0]+[0]) \\
&= f([0]) \\
&= 1
\end{alignat}
\begin{alignat}{1}
(\psi_f([0]+\_))(2) &= (f([0]+\_)f^{-1})(2) \\
&= f(([0]+\_)(f^{-1}(2))) \\
&= f([0]+[1]) \\
&= f([1]) \\
&= 2
\end{alignat}
\begin{alignat}{1}
(\psi_f([0]+\_))(3) &= (f([0]+\_)f^{-1})(3) \\
&= f(([0]+\_)(f^{-1}(3)) \\
&= f([0]+[2]) \\
&= f([2]) \\
&= 3
\end{alignat}
\begin{alignat}{1}
(\psi_f([0]+\_))(4) &= (f([0]+\_)f^{-1})(4) \\
&= f(([0]+\_)(f^{-1}(4)) \\
&= f([0]+[3]) \\
&= f([3]) \\
&= 4
\end{alignat}
Therefore:
$$\psi_f([0]+\_)=()$$
With the same recipe, you will find:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\psi_f([1]+\_) &&=(1234) \\
&\psi_f([2]+\_) &&=(13)(24) \\
&\psi_f([3]+\_) &&=(1432) \\
\end{alignat}
whence: $$\mathbb Z_4\stackrel{\psi_f\varphi}{\cong}\{(),(1234),(13)(24),(1432)\}\le S_4$$
Other choices of the bijection $f$ in $(1)$ will lead to different subgroups of $S_4$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4$.

Can you mimick this whole routine with $\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_2$?